# Difference between “pragmatics” and “pragmatism”?

Tags: meaning, pragmatics

**pragmatic**

adjective prag·mat·ic \prag-ˈma-tik\

: dealing with the problems that exist in a specific situation in a reasonable and logical way instead of depending on ideas and theories (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pragmatic)

**pragmatics**

noun plural but singular or plural in construction prag·mat·ics \prag-ˈma-tiks\

linguistics : the study of what words mean in particular situations
(merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pragmatics)

**pragmatism**

noun prag·ma·tism \ˈprag-mə-ˌti-zəm\

: a reasonable and logical way of doing things or of thinking about problems that is based on dealing with specific situations instead of on ideas and theories (merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pragmatism)

---

Pragmatics by definition is a term used in linguistics. But I think that people us pragmatics synonymously with pragmatism. Is that right? Are they synonyms or not? When should I use one or the other?

Comment: "pragmatics" and "pragmatism" are not synonyms, and the definitions you quote are correct.  "Pragmatics" refers to a field of study concerning the relationship between a language and the people who speak it.  This use is not actually confined to linguistics -- it's also a discipline within philosophy, and linguists became interested in it later than philosophers.

Comment: You could also include "ideals" alongside "ideas and theories". In a democracy, pragmatic politicians manage to strike compromises with those who do not share their ideals but have different ideals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they are synonyms.  Pragmatics is to science as Pragmatism is to engineering.  One is the study, the other is the practice. Do people use them as synonyms? Not in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

It may be helpful to consider the difference between pragmatic and pragmatism.

Pragmatic and pragmatism are not interchangeable synonyms - i.e. neither is used to replace the other so

---

*My boss is **pragmatic**.*

---

would not be changed to

---

*My boss is **pragmatism**.*

---

Pragmatic is the adjective form of the noun pragmatism. So we could say:

---

*She failed to recognize when it was inappropriate to be **pragmatic**.*

Or

*Where ***pragmatism*** prioritizes action over thinking, it's especially prone to unreasonable and logically irrational decision-making that exacerbates problems rather than solve them.*

---

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are these your own examples?  Please attribute your sources.